# iOS first time user tutorial

Tags: ios

I'm building an iPhone app and want to create a 1st time use tutorial for the user. I've seen some other apps use popover style baloons to guide the user through the UI and I'd like to do that as well. I have a popover library. What's the best way to create and track the steps of the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with NSUserDefaults.  Just trigger some `BOOL`-ean values to change as each part finishes.  I assume you want to continue the tutorial if the user quits the app, so this would be your best and easiest bet.

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL`s for each dialog? Persisted however you want - NSUserDefaults or plist, json file, xml, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` if you want to setting to sync across devices using iCloud. If the user doesn't have iCloud configured it will just store it locally.